# How to append to the end of a line a searched pattern several times in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I have the following strings.

[ABC-10, some_text], [EDFG-24, some_text2], ...and so on.

I need to add to the end of every such line the following: ABC#10#EDFG#24#... and so on.

Here is my search pattern.

```
\\(\\w\\{-}\\)-\\(\\d\\{1,2\\}\\)
```

I can futher use in substition `\1` (letters) and `\2` (digits) to get the needed part of the pattern. But how to print all matching patterns at once?

If i write

```
:%s/search_pattern/&#\1#\2
```

i get only the first matching pattern, i.e. ABC#10. How to add all of them?

Comment: Is the number of `[ABC-10, some_text]` the same for all your lines ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a hard task for a regular expression because you have to assume parse the whole line to insert data, and you cannot come back to parse it again (unless using a recursive one, that I think `vim` is lack of), so one dirty option (just for fun) is to use a loop and apply the same regular expression multiple times, like:

```
:for i in range(10) | s/\v((\w{-})-(\d{1,2}))(.*\2#\3)@!(.*)$/\1\5#\2#\3/e | endfor
```

It does grouping for the text you are searching and use a non-positive look-ahead assert to check that part has not been added.

Note that I assume that there will not be more than ten blocks in the same line, because I won't loop more times, you can increment (or decrement that number). Also note that for each line `vim` will try it the ten times, but it won't complain because I've used the `/e` flag to silent it.

The result that yields in my example:

```
[ABC-10, some_text], [EDFG-24, some_text2]#ABC#10#EDFG#24
```

Answer (score 1):

add `/g` at the end of replace command:

```
:%s/search_pattern/&#\1#\2/g
```

Comment: It won't work, because it leaves only the last occurance of a pattern.